# how to count the same vectors from two bitset in java

Tags: java

Sorry really new for Java, just try to figure out:

```
public int findSimilarity(Listing l) throws ListingException {
    if (keyVectors == null || l == null) {
        throw new ListingException("Missing listing");
    }

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i  < keyVectors.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < l.getKeyVector().length(); j++) {
            if (keyVectors.get(i) == l.getKeyVector().get(j)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

which Listing is a abstract class and this method is in a class extends from Listing,  what it does is to count the number of same vectors in the input BitSet (Listing l) and the local BitSet. And I know it doesn't work in this way.. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: I don't think it's possible to answer this question without more information about the methods and classes you're using.

Comment: There is a method called getVectors() in this extended class and this class is extends from Listing

Answer (score 1):

Please don't answer. This is a university assignment.